# Getting user data from facebook graph api but user id doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, mismatch

I am using facebook graph api as below;

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/search?q=search+string+here&type=user&access_token=accessTOKENhere
```

and it results as;

```
"data": [
      {
         "name": "search+string+here",
         "id": "10152202833927632"
      }
   ],
```

When I was first testing this I was using the id like;

```
http://www.facebook.com/10152202833927632
```

and I was able to see the page of the user. But now I realize that this link doesn't work. When I check from other sources, the real id of the user is not same with this one.

Does anyone know why graph api returns me a different kind of (not working) id?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The ID is an app scoped user ID. Do a request to graph.facebook.com/10152202833927632 and in the request there is a link property that you can use to link to that user

Comment: I am making a request from the browser as you said;

graph.facebook.com/10152202833927632

and the result is;

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}

I tried adding an access_token to it but it also gave a message like;

"error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist
}

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

App-scoped IDs were introduced in Graph API v2.0. Read more about how they work and how you handle them [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog).

Comment: Thanks for the guide! As far I understand that the "original id"s that I got at first time I tried were the ones (probably) that logged into my app maybe.

Comment: For users who have NOT logged into your app, the IDs they're referred as differs depending on the version of the Graph API you're calling. v1.0 will be global IDs, while v2.0 will be app-scoped ones. Worth trying is changing 'v2.0' in your call to 'v1.0'. You can read all this in the URL linked in my original answer!

Comment: Thank again! Well actually my path is like /{object} (so it is v 1.0 as described at the link you referred) but getting app-scoped ids, not the global ones still.

My query is like ;

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=search+string&access_token=token

but still getting app-scoped id's. ("id": "10152202833927632")

Have any idea?